# Grep for a variable in a file

Tags: shell

I want to grep the following patterns in the file /root/scripts/list.txt:

```
'^"123"^'
'^"456"^'
'^"789"^'
```

So I write code like below in my shell script

```
myvar=-F -e '^"123"^' -e '^"456"^' -e '^"789"^'
grep $myvar /root/scripts/list.txt
```

(Pattern will change every time, so I created a string with `myvar`)

It is giving a `null` output, but when I run the command below I'm getting the required output:

```
grep -F -e '^"123"^' -e '^"456"^' -e '^"789"^' /root/scripts/list.txt
```

Can some one please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is your use of quotes, but you haven't accurately shown how you're setting myvar.  (I assume you're not writing `myvar=-f -e '^...`, since that would try to run a command named `-e` and you would probably get an error of the form `-e: command not found.).  Edit your question to show your code.

Comment: I suspect you just need to omit the single quotes around each term in the assignment of myvar, but it's difficult to say without more detail.

Comment: Try `myvar='-F -e ^"123"^ -e ^"456"^'`

Comment: If you are using bash, consider using bash arrays: `myvar=( -F -e '^"123"^' )` and `grep ${myvar[@]}`

Comment: Thanks William Pursell for your suggestion to omit single quotes around the id. I wonder how this is working in shell script and not working when I run that grep command in command prompt. Please explain.